# How to do the post sending Limitation on Mongodb

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am on MongoDB-Nodejs Environment. I have two Types of User i.e

```
Normal User: This class Users can Only post 1 Blog per day.
Special Class User: This User can Post the Blog 5 times a day.
```

My db Structure is Like this:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("7f5797bb5000e4f1c9c85d39g"),
    "userid" : "1",
    "Post" : 'Hello world',
    "Heading" : 'Testing',
    "createdate" : ISODate("2018-02-16T06:35:33.364Z"),
    "__v" : 0
}... upto 100 entries
```

Now for doing this task I have a class of user.

What I did on my nodejs Code is like if else condition.

```
if(user == 'normal') {
  //Calculating the length of data
  if (data.length < 5){
     Value save function execute which can do the entry on collection
  } else {
    console.log('Your daily Limit Exceed);
  }
} else {
  if (data.length < 1){
     Value save function execute which can do the entry on collection
  } else {
    console.log('Your daily Limit Exceed);
  }
}
```

Now these things perfectly fine for me. The main problem is that particular user which exceeded the limit will always ban or not able to do an entry on collection.

I want this logic but only for One Day. Next day the same user can post the Blog According to the class criteria i.e Limit 1 or 5.

Anyone suggest me how I can Do this. I know there are some Timestamp Criteria by which we can do this. But not Getting the Exact Solution

Any help is really appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Fetch only posts that are created on the current date & compare the results length. I'd use moment.js to create start of the date, with `moment().startOf('day').toDate()`

```
db.collection('posts')
  .find({createdate: {$gte: moment().startOf('day').toDate()}})
  .toArray(...)
```